# sql query exception in java

Tags: java, sql

I am trying to connect my java project with database in netbeans. I have a table named task_table and i'm trying to add some values on that table.
Here is my code

```
Connection con1;
PreparedStatement insert;
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
     String name1= addtaskname.getText();
     String name2= addtaskdate.getText();
     String name3= addtasktime.getText();
     
     
     

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/jesin_virtual","root","");
        insert = con1.prepareStatement("insert into task_table(Task Name,Task Date,Task Time) values (?,?,?)");
         insert.setString(1, name1);
         insert.setString(2,name2 );
         insert.setString(3,name3);
         insert.executeUpdate();
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Task Added sucessfully");
```

and i got this exception:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax
```

Comment: Can column names have white spaces in them in MariaDB? The quickest way to solve this would be to run the query you want in some SQL browser first, then once you see it is ok, you can move it to your code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
insert into task_table(Task Name,Task Date,Task Time) values (?,?,?)
                           ^         ^         ^
```

If the column names really contain blanks, then you need backticks around the names (`Task Name`), else change the names to what they really are (Task_Name maybe?).

Answer (score 0):

Please correct SQL query inside as below...

if in your database column names contains space so please use below query

```
"insert into task_table("Task Name","Task Date","Task Time") values (?,?,?)"
```

if in your database column names contains _ so please use below query

```
 "insert into task_table(Task_Name,Task_Date,Task_Time) values (?,?,?)"
```

Comment: The double quotes needs to be escaped. :-)

Comment: Yes you are right but if the table in database have space inside so need to add "" if database table contains _ so need to add _

Comment: I meant "insert into ... (\"table a\", \"table b\") values (?,?)".

Comment: If you want to have double quotes in a string in Java, you'll escape them with backslashes, just as kometen has shown. Unlike in standard SQL, in MariaDB the double quotes usually mean string literal, not name delimiter. So, be aware of using the appropriate ANSI_QUOTES mode, when using double quotes in MariaDB (and MySQL for that matter).